# How can I restrict users from editing Google Apps Script while they should be able to access and edit the sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet which is shared with multiple users. They should be able to view and edit the sheets. The sheet uses apps scripts to calculate certain fields. I don't want the users to modify the scripts, practically they don't even need to see the scripts, can I restrict it somehow?

I tried to find options for restricting users in the Apps Scripts settings, but couldn't find the option. I also tried searching Google's documentation, but I only found sheet and range protection or Apps Script authorization scopes.

Comment: Turn your script into an addon

Comment: `I tried to find options for restricting users in the Apps Scripts settings, but couldn't find the option.` If a user can edit your spreadsheet, then they can also access the Project Editor and edit your scripts. A workaround is to create a `standalone script` though there are certain methods that are only available to `bound` scripts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Tedinoz, I'll look into standalone scripts